# My C code keeps on going and doesn't return any result even when all the loop and conditional statements are satisfied

Tags: c

I have tried OnlineGBD debugging tool and Visual Studio as well, but neither of them helped much.

If I enter the input of "1 1 1 1 8" the program still runs and doesn't return the required output.

I researched a bit and people online said that the problem is with the triple declaration of the variables, however I changed the name of the variables for each function and the problem still persists.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int IPAndSubnetMaskInput(int IPAndSubnetMaskFirstOctate, int IPAndSubnetMaskSecondOctate, int IPAndSubnetMaskThirdOctate, int IPAndSubnetMaskFourthOctate, int IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput) {

    printf("Please input an IPv4 address followed by the subnetmask (must either be 8, 16, 24, or 32) in the following format: 192 168 1 1 32: \n"); //Statement to ask for IP and submask input and puts the inputs into a variable to calculate Broadcast IP
    int IPv4AndSubmask = scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &IPAndSubnetMaskFirstOctate, &IPAndSubnetMaskSecondOctate, &IPAndSubnetMaskThirdOctate, &IPAndSubnetMaskFourthOctate, &IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput); //Input function

    while (!(IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput == 8 || IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput == 16 || IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput == 24 || IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput == 32)) { //Initializing loop to evaluate whether subnet is correct or not

        printf("Your submask is wrong. Please enter a value that's either 8, 16, 24, or 32: \n");
        scanf("%d", &IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput);

    if (IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput == 8 || IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput == 16 || IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput == 24 || IPAndSubnetMaskSubnetInput == 32)
        { break; }
    }
    return IPv4AndSubmask;//function returns the value of IP octates and the subnet mask for the program to calculate
}


int broadcastCalculator(int broadcastFirstOctate, int broadcastSecondOctate, int broadcastThirdOctate, int broadcastFourthOctate, int broadcastSubnetInput) { //Declaration of first function for first Assignment point

    IPAndSubnetMaskInput(broadcastFirstOctate, broadcastSecondOctate, broadcastThirdOctate, broadcastFourthOctate, broadcastSubnetInput);

    while (0 == 0) {
        if (broadcastSubnetInput == 8) { //Conditional statement for submask of 8
            printf("The broadcast IP is:\t%hhu\t%hhu\t%hhu\t255\t\n", broadcastFirstOctate, broadcastSecondOctate, broadcastThirdOctate);//Program will print the Broadcast IP of firstOctate  secondOctate thirdOctate 255
            break;
        }
        else if (broadcastSubnetInput == 16) {//Conditional statement for submask of 16
            printf("The broadcast IP is:\t%hhu\t%hhu\t255\t255\t\n", broadcastFirstOctate, broadcastSecondOctate);//Program will print the Broadcast IP of firstOctate  secondOctate 255 255
            break;
        }
        else if (broadcastSubnetInput == 24) {//Conditional statement for submask of 24
            printf("The broadcast IP is:\t%hhu\t255\t255\t255\t\n", broadcastFirstOctate);//Program will print the Broadcast IP of firstOctate  255 255 255
            break;
        }
        else if (broadcastSubnetInput == 32) {//Conditional statement for submask of 32
            printf("The broadcast IP is:\t255\t255\t255\t255");//Program will print the Broadcast IP of 255  255 255 255
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int firstOctate, secondOctate, thirdOctate, fourthOctate, subnetInput;
    broadcastCalculator(firstOctate, secondOctate, thirdOctate, fourthOctate, subnetInput);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Parameters are passed by value into functions. This means that the values inside `IPAndSubnetMaskInput` are copies of the values in the outer function. This is the same princinple behind passing pointers to the variables when calling `scanf`, instead of variables. I also don't understand the need for the `while` loop inside your `broadCalculator`, there is no way that these variables can change inside the loop, so what's the point in repeating this block endlessly?

Comment: `while (0 == 0)` is a redundant loop and will be an infinite loop if `broadcastSubnetInput` is not equal to 32, 24,16 or 8

Comment: @Spikatrix I need an infinite loop until the user fixes their error of inputting a subnet that's not one of those 4.

Comment: @Groo I don't really understand that comment. I'm very new to programming, so any further elaboration would help.

Comment: @Heartbreakkid: when you write `scanf("%d", &x);`, the ampersand is there for a reason. You are passing the value of the address of `x`, so that modifications inside `scanf` can affect `x`. If you have a function `something(x);` and `x` is an integer, then this function will get a copy of the integer **value**, not its address.

Comment: @Groo on which lines have I made that mistake, precisely?

Comment: OT: regarding: `{ break; }`  and `nt firstOctate, secondOctate, thirdOctate, fourthOctate, subnetInput;`  For ease of readability and understanding; 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  3) for readability and printability, Please honor the right margin (usually column 72 or 80).

Answer (score 0):

when the posted code is compiled:

```
gcc    -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -c "untitled2.c"  
untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled2.c:50:5: warning: ‘firstOctate’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     broadcastCalculator(firstOctate, secondOctate, thirdOctate, fourthOctate, subnetInput);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
untitled2.c:50:5: warning: ‘secondOctate’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
untitled2.c:50:5: warning: ‘thirdOctate’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
untitled2.c:50:5: warning: ‘fourthOctate’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
untitled2.c:50:5: warning: ‘subnetInput’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
Compilation finished successfully.
```

That statement: "Compilation finished successfully."  only means the compiler produced code for some 'work around' for the problems.  It does not mean the produced code is correct.

Every one of the 'used uninitialized' messages is telling you about some Undefined Behavior.

So whayever the code is outputting is meaningless.

Suggest fixing the code so it cleanly compiles